# Dynamic point clusters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, clustering

I have a point layer with singular points set with high accuracy to the position of certain sites, each point representing one site. There are 8 different types of site. When representing these points on a smaller scale map, the image becomes confusing, however.

I am looking for a way of clustering points of the same type into bigger points for representation on small scale maps. Therefore the size of the new clusterpoints should correspond to the number of points cluster within them.

There should be a workaround using buffers and spatial joins, but I assume, that there is a more elegant sollution?

I am using QGIS 2.18 on a Windows 7 PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are ready to upgrade, qgis 3 has a "point cluster" renderer that do exactly what you are looking for.

With qgis 2 you could try the "Point displacement" renderer, at last it will prevent overlap

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. In case anyone - like me - does not find this feature instantly: It is an option in the styling options of the point layer. A description can be found here: https://anitagraser.com/2017/06/13/even-more-aggregations-qgis-point-cluster-renderer/