# Filter nearby points leaving only one in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, filter

I have a shapefile with points, however the algorithm gave not one point per location, but several. I would need to filter these points, so that there is only one point, does not matter which one, from each group of points. The example of original points and points after filtration can bee seen below:
[image]

I know that this could be done using SAGA GIS Points filter option, however as I have 3.22 million of these points, the tool is not working. I also tried [Dynamic point clusters in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281547/dynamic-point-clusters-in-qgis) solution with QGIS Point displacement tool, however, at first it seems that points has been filtered leaving only one, but when zooming in, one point is really 3 points. Also this gives a wrong total point count.

[image]

Is there other option how this could be done using QGIS or other tools? Perhaps a python solution?

Comment: Approx. 1 to 1.5 meters

Comment: I did not, wasn't sure if with 3.2 million points it's the best solution, but of course that's a way to do it

Comment: Is there attribute table field that are in common ? You want to keep one point per group and keep attribute table ? Get the number of point ? Have you tried cluster tool (in a selection of 10 000 to test)

Comment: @CorentinLemaitre points attribute table consists of x, y coordinate and unique ID, but attributes are not so important in this case. I just need to get one point per group. Will take a look at cluster tool, thanks!

Comment: @BERA no, but I would try any new solution. You have something in mind?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651386/thin-out-many-st-points/62344747#62344747

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use DBSCAN clustering to assign nearby points the same CLUSTER_ID. This algorithm is very fast.

1. **DBScan clustering** to assign nearby points the same cluster. I used min points = 2 and distance 100 m for my building dataset
2. **Random selection within subsets** to select one point per cluster
3. **Select by expression** to Add to the selection all points with `"CLUSTER_ID" is null`

Then **Copy Selected features** to a new dataset.

For my 1,2 million points this is taking 15 s

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This really worked. With 3.2 million points, min points = 2 and distance 1 m, DBScan clustering took only approx. 40 seconds. However, I still found some groups with no points selected.