# Select points within a distance of each other in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, select

I want to select and remove 'duplicate' points that are within 200' of each other in QGIS. Meaning I want to leave 1 point and remove any others that are within 200' of it. I tried to buffer and select overlapping buffers but that also would select the 1 point I want to leave. Any thoughts?

From the image: Point 1 is 134' from Point 2 so I only want to leave 1 of those points. Point 3 is 310' from Point 2 so both those points should be left.

[image: image of 3 points within certain distances]

Comment: this more or less the same question which is answered here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/394193/87346